# Laravel (ver 6) php artisan route:list return "Target class does not exist" error with production environment (worked fine in local environment)

Tags: php, vue.js, production-environment, laravel-6

I'm using laravel 6 for BE and vuejs for FE. Wtih my local environment ( built on xampp server ), everything was fine. But, when I deployed the app to the server(Lamp server with ubuntu 18.04), I got the following error when I tried to run "php artisan route:list".

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Masterdata\CountryController] does not exist.
>
> at /var/www/html/performance.goautobot.chat/public_html/performance/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:806

```
        try {
             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
       } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
```

> ```
>          throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
>        }
> ```

And some APIs are not working. The weird part is both "Roles" and "Countries" have exactly the same structure as the following but only apis related to "Roles" are working got "BindingResolutionException" error when I tried with Postman.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {    
  // Countries     
  Route::get('masterdata/countries', 'Masterdata\CountryController@index');      
  // Roles    
  Route::get('masterdata/roles', 'Masterdata\RoleController@index');     
}
```

I tried to solve it by running the commands like "composer dump-autoload" and "php artisan config:cache" but it didn't fix the problem. Also, tried to remove the project folder and made a new installation and deployment.

Please let me know how to fix the issue. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Another obvious step to check, which you may have overlooked, is does the class and namespace declaration in the file match the file path? It could be that you have a file at that location, but it contains the wrong class (e.g. misspelt name).

Comment: please check the name of the folder, and more important, to have set the namespace at the beginning of that controller file

Comment: @fubar, Thank you so much for your answer. Both of the controllers(Role and Country are under the same name space "namespace App\Http\Controllers\Masterdata;" and I've checked all the spellings of each controller and class. They are correct and work fine in my local.

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions are `644`?

Comment: @fubar, I've checked file permissions and it's correct already. thanks

Comment: @fubar, Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I found out a controller(not Country) which is under the same namespace and has a misspelling. It was neglected somehow in my local and it made me hard to debug. Thanks again for your answers. It helped me :)

Comment: @Berto99, Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I found out a controller(not Country) which is under the same namespace and has a misspelling. It was neglected somehow in my local and it made me hard to debug. Thanks again for your answer. It helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with HomeController, then I checked the routes in the web.php file,
I found it was like the following

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

Then I changed this to the following according to the directory where the Homecontoller resides

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');
```

after that, it worked correctly.

So Please check your controller directory,

if your controller directory is "App\Http\Controllers\Masterdata\CountryController" then add this in the route. it will be like following

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Masterdata\CountryController');
```

I tried to explain according to my scenario,
Please let me know if this helps and please pardon me if I have got something wrong